# Are there good reasons to NOT invite my boss to Thanksgiving dinner?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, employer-relations, socializing

I have a pretty solid professional relationship with my boss. We also get along well personally and share some things in common that don't relate to work that we talk about. I have a suspicion, but am not sure, that my boss doesn't yet have plans for Thanksgiving.

It's going to be a moderately sized crowd with a mix of adults and kids. So my boss wouldn't be very much on the spot, but also not left out. My boss doesn't have young kids to bring, but does like kids in general.

I have no issues with my boss seeing my home and personal living space.

I can't really think of any downsides. But I'd like to hear what others have to say.

Comment: It's riskier to have your boss over for a larger gathering (alcohol, rowdiness, political arguing, destructive kids - whichever of these your family is most prone to) than to just meet your family and see your house.

Comment: The question is, do you want to be friends with your boss or keep it a professional thing? Don't invite "professional" friends to events with your "personal" friends, unless you want them to be "personal" friends of yours and know and share all the stuff you only share with those.

Comment: So you are looking for reasons not to invite your boss? If you can't think of any downsides, then be optimistic and invite your boss.

Comment: One of my employees invited me and my oldest son over for Thanksgiving as my wife and the other kids were out of country, It was really nice and as far as I can tell everyone had a good time with no impact on work relations at all. Even bosses can be regular humans at times.

Answer (score 19):

By doing *anything* which mixes your work and personal lives, you are taking a risk. What happens if your partner falls out with your boss? What happens if someone else at the dinner reveals that story about what you got up to at college, and your boss takes offence? etc, etc. Life is easier if you keep things separate.

That said, I've had my boss round to my house at every company I've ever worked at, and nothing bad came of it - but it was always *purely* as a social event, and we made sure not to discuss work at anything more than a trivial level. If nothing else because my better half would shout at me if I tried to discuss work at a social event :-)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the old rule as best as you can: "don't mix business with pleasure".

You get along well professionally, but have you ever dealt with him in a crisis situation?  People are **funky** in a crisis.  Getting him close to your family and what's inside your house gives your boss *leverage* in a crisis situation, and can alter how he makes decisions about you.

There's no telling what things your boss may see in your home that can be used against you in the future.  Got nice things?  It may incite some jealousy.  Do you keep house in a much different way from your boss?  It may incite some dissonance.  It's *little* things.

Keep your boss out of your personal affairs.

Comment: Your example is a little too specific. A little paranoid, too.

Comment: @AndreiROM There's not one bit in this answer that I'd call paranoid - the examples are all things I've seen in real life happen. Some people (some bosses included) just look for excuses not to like someone else.